# How to make AWS credentials accessible to boto in django environment?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm unable to create an S3 connection in my django environment via django-s3-storages middleware (I'm getting a 403 response from S3).

Boto doesn't seem to be able to pick up the environment settings, and I suspect this is the cause (the traceback isn't helping much). As a diagnosis in `manage.py shell`:

```
import boto
boto.connect_s3()
>>> boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials

from django.conf import settings
boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
>>> S3Connection:s3.amazonaws.com
```

[The docs](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage) (and other posts) indicate that these settings should work:

```
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage'

#S3 settings from https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "yyy"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket"
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = "boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat"

# Make user uploaded files public
AWS_S3_BUCKET_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_MAX_AGE_SECONDS = 60*60*24*365 # 1 year
AWS_S3_GZIP = True
```

Why isn't boto able to connect?

Comment: The django storage middleware uses its own `S3Storage` class. That class has knowledge of django's `settings.py` and will use `settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` if they're configured. `boto3` by itself has no knowledge of the django settings file, so it doesn't use anything you configure in that file. That's why you have to specify the key and secret to `boto3` when trying to establish an S3 connection.

Comment: Thanks, if you put it as an answer I'll accept. Now I'm back where I started unfortunately; I still don't know what's causing the 403s.

Comment: HTTP/403 from S3 can actually mean many things. One thing to check is whether or not the user/role your credentials are for has access to list the bucket you're trying to access. If you try to access a non-existent key in a bucket, but don't have permissions to list the bucket contents, S3 will return a 403. If you can recreate the problem via code or can show log information, you can post a new question/ask me for help.

Comment: Yes, I have verified the credentials. I've reformulated the question and would be grateful if you can think of anything else: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41399502/3790954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django storage middleware uses its own [`S3Storage` class](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage/blob/master/django_s3_storage/storage.py#L44). That class has knowledge of django's settings.py and will use `settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` if they're configured.

`boto3` by itself has no knowledge of the django settings file, so it doesn't use anything you configure in that file. That's why you have to specify the key and secret to `boto3` when trying to establish an S3 connection.

Comment: How about boto3 application which is not aware of django settings?

Comment: @ManjitKumar set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in your environment, or use [any of the methods specified here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html).