# Getting Http403 when saving files through django s3 middleware (but can save using boto in shell)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have been trying to save user uploaded files to my s3 bucket via my django application. I'm using the [`django-s3-storage`](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage) middleware, but I keep getting:

> S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden (Access Denied)

I'm using these settings:

```
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage'

#S3 settings from https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "yyy"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket"
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = "boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat"

# Make user uploaded files public
AWS_S3_BUCKET_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_MAX_AGE_SECONDS = 60*60*24*365 # 1 year
AWS_S3_GZIP = True
```

And I know the credentials are valid:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from django.conf import settings
conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
b = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')
key = b.get_key('test.txt')
print(key.get_contents_as_string())
>>>this is a test
from boto.s3.key import Key
k = Key(b)
k.key = 'test2.txt'
k.set_contents_from_string('another test')
>>>12
```

I've set a completely open CORS policy too (while trying to get this working from my dev machine):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So what's stopping me authenticating via the middleware? (Or what else could be causing the 403?)

#### Edit:

bucket policy allowing access to IAM user `production` for bucket `my-bucket`. I've removed the user ARN digits and replaced with `x`.

```
{
    "Version": "2016-12-30",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/production"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The error is not a signature error as per [this bug](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage/issues/28). I'm on django 1.10, boto 2.45, django-s3-storage 0.9.11.

```
S3ResponseError at /the-url/

S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

#### Edit 2:

OK, this weird thing happened (I don't recall having changed anything in the settings to cause this): I upload a file, and no error is returned. The file is saved as per the model definition `image0 = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images")`. The file is then available at `https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/productimages/myimage.jpg` (huh? why?). It is ***not*** available at `http://my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/media/productimages/myimage.jpg`, nor is it visible in my bucket's `media/productimages/myimage.jpg`.

So it seems that something funny is going on with either s3 or the middleware. Any ideas?

Comment: The authentication seems fine. Can you show the policy for the role/user your credentials are for, especially in regards to its S3 permissions? Also, I did some digging - what version of `django-s3-storage` are you using? The current released versions might [have a bug related to this](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage/issues/28) that may be fixed if you use the `master` branch version.

Comment: Please add your s3 bucket policy in this question. I faced the same problem and I found the bug in s3 bucket policy.

Comment: I've added the additional info. Thanks.

Comment: I know two things that can cause this. 1) is your django app running in some form of virtualization(docker, vbox, etc.) sometimes the clock gets out of sync, this causes issues with AWS. You just have do some `set date...` stuff from the CLI 2) Can you use `aws s3` to fetch and manipulate the objects under the posted policies? I'd verify these are correctly setup and working before trying to configure your django bits.

Comment: 1. It's not running on a virtualized environment. 2. As per the python shell code and using boto, with the IAM user credentials I can use s3 to fetch and manipulate objects. I just can't seem to do it in the django environment via the middleware.

Comment: Bucket policy apply to users..are you not using a role for your ec2 instance running django? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html

Comment: I'm not using a role. I'm not using an ec2 instance; I'm hosting the django app on another VPS provider (not amazon).

Answer (score 0):

Using bucket described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html). There are two access methods - path, and virtual hosted. More on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html). Is your bucket name is DNS compliant?